# Where are Primavera's old baseline dates stored after rescheduling the project?

Tags: pm-software, software-development, pmi-framework

Any idea Where are `Primevera`'s old baseline dates are stored after rescheduling the project?
We can see the old dates in the Client but I want to query the database to get all the dates which were used before the current baseline dates.

Answer (score 1):

Check this LinkedIn thread for same question and discussion.  [See the post by the user Gene Greiff, which contains the following code](http://www.linkedin.com/groups/How-does-Primavera-maintains-store-3305048.S.221621845?_mSplash=1):

```
Declare @BaseLineName varchar (255) 
Declare @BaseLineType varchar(255) 
set @BaseLineName = 'Project Nano - B2' 
set @BaseLineType = 'Mid Project Status Baseline' 


select * 
from dbo.PROJWBS pw 
inner join PROJECT pj on pj.proj_id = pw.proj_id 
inner join BASETYPE bt on bt.base_type_id = pj.base_type_id 
where pw.wbs_name = @BaseLineName 
AND bt.base_type = @BaseLineType
```

Comment: Hi Sreedhar, can you [edit] your post and quote the LinkedIn answer here? We ask that answers be self contained on our site. If the link were to ever break, and you quoted the answer here, your answer would still be useful to hundreds of future visitors who come across this post. Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Congrats on earning the bounty. With [Raju Gujarati's help](http://pm.stackexchange.com/users/4714/raju-gujarati), I edited your post with the actual code. Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thanks a lot it helps.  Hope it helps who asked this question camelbrush.

Comment: Thanks guys, but it didn't help much. I read already read that post before posting here. Like the OP there, I too have moved on to another project right now.